# How to extract the page name in Google analytics events

Tags: php, google-analytics

i tried to look for an answer in Google developer page but without success,

my question is regarding the below code:

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'name-of-the-page', 'Click', 'game-name']);"
```

where its written "name-of-the-page" i would like to extract the page name so that i could see the name of each page where the event occurred in the analytic panel, how can i do it in PHP and especially in this Google analytic function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **don't have** to track the page name, it's already caught by Google Analytics. On your "Events" page, you can show it as a secondary dimension :

[image]

With this, you can track and sort your events by Category/Action/Label, and still know the page where they occured.

---

Please note this code has changed with the last versions of Google Analytics (`ga.js` became `analytics.js`) :

```
// old code
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action', 'Label']); 

// new code
ga('send', 'event', 'Category', 'Action', 'Label');
```

[Old code (`ga.js`) documentation.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)
[New code (`analytics.js`) documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Comment: Can you please attach the source/documentation for the new code format?